# Installing agents on solaris remotely

Tags: solaris, uptime, uptime-monitoring

In regard to Uptime.
I want to install the agents on solaris machine remotely through putty.
Now for that, I have established(logged in) a connection to that system successfully.

following [this](http://docs.uptimesoftware.com/display/UT72/Installing+Agents+on+Solaris), my next step would be to "**Using a file transfer method such as FTP, transfer the archive containing the Agent to the system on which you want to install it. You should copy the archive to a temporary directory on the system.**"

Now my problem is that i am unable to transfer the archive containing the agent, to the system on which i logged in through putty.

I have searched this command to transfer the files **rcp machinename:source destination**

here my machine name is:

\uptime-share.uptimesoftware.com\css\Releases\Agents\Solaris

source : uptimeagent-7.2.1-solaris-sparc

destination : 172.20.98.14/tmp

but after using this command i get the message connection refused.

Could someone help me to do this.
I used this command

**rcp 172.20.32.11:/css/Releases/Agents/Solaris:uptimeagent-7.2.1-solaris-sparc 172.20.98.14/tmp**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `scp`?

Comment: `rcp` is insecure and disabled by default on modern Solaris releases.  `scp` is the secure, preferred, and enabled by default alternative.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: yes thank you very much guys it worked for me...and thanks alanc to be more specific